# How to put data into clickable list tile, when tile is clicked show relevant data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a clickable list tiles of driver UID. On the list tiles the drivers UID will be shown. On tapping the tile, relevant information about that specific driver such as name and phone will be shown on screen.

This is as far as I have been able to come.

[This is what my RTDB looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R28mo.jpg)

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class DriverListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DriverListScreen({key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String idScreen = "DriverListScreen";

  @override
  _DriverListScreenState createState() => _DriverListScreenState();
}

class _DriverListScreenState extends State<DriverListScreen> {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  List driverList = [];
  var num = 0;

  getDriverDetails() async {
    // Get the driver UİD, show it on a clickable list.
    // When list is clicked, show the relevant info
    databaseReference.child("users").child("driver").onValue.listen(
      (event) {
        setState(() {
          var value = event.snapshot.value;
          var driverSKIDS = value.keys;
          for (var driverSKID in driverSKIDS) {
            driverList.add(driverSKID);
            print(driverList[num]);
            num += 1;
          }
        });
      },
    );
    return driverList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Entering Scafold");
    getDriverDetails();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Driver List",
          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: driverList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        tileColor: Colors.blue,
                        selectedTileColor: Colors.red,
                        title: Text(driverList[index]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) to handle this.

Check out the code below.
I added a `Driver` class to hold the driver data and I removed unused code.

```dart
class DriverListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DriverListScreen({key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String idScreen = "DriverListScreen";

  @override
  _DriverListScreenState createState() => _DriverListScreenState();
}

class _DriverListScreenState extends State<DriverListScreen> {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  List<Driver> driverList = [];

  Future<List<Driver>> getDriverDetails() async {
    // Get the driver UİD, show it on a clickable list.
    // When list is clicked, show the relevant info
    databaseReference.child("users").child("driver").onValue.listen(
      (event) {
        setState(() {
          var value = event.snapshot.value;
          driverList = Map.from(value)
              .values
              .map((e) => Driver.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
              .toList();
        });
      },
    );
    return driverList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Entering Scafold");
    getDriverDetails();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Driver List",
          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: driverList.isEmpty
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: driverList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                final Driver driver = driverList[index];
                final String driverEmail = driver.email;
                final String driverName = driver.name;
                final String driverPhone = driver.phone;
                final String driverRandomId = driver.randomId;
                final String driverUID = driver.uid;

                return Card(
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(driverUID),
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(driverName),
                        Text(driverEmail),
                        Text(driverPhone),
                        Text(driverRandomId),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ));
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}

class Driver {
  final String email;
  final String name;
  final String phone;
  final String randomId;
  final String uid;

  Driver({
    required this.email,
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
    required this.randomId,
    required this.uid,
  });

  static Driver fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Driver(
      email: json['email'],
      name: json['name'],
      phone: json['phone'],
      randomId: json['random id'],
      uid: json['user uid'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my late reply. However, thank you very much. This worked very well. I will now try to understand the code you have written. Good day.